# PHPExcel freezePane() makes it impossible to scroll horizontally if columns doesn't fit the window

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I need to freeze first six rows and "infinite" columns which I want to scroll through but all I can do with PHPExcel class is scroll columns after the selected cell and rows below it.

The function is doing what you would achieve in MS Excel by selecting a cell (let's say T7) and clicking `View->Freeze Panes`.

What I need can be achieved in MS Excel by selecting a row 7 (not the cell but complete row on the left "ruler") and click `View->Freeze Panes`.
By doing that you have first 6 rows frozen and you can scroll vertically **but more importantly, since infinite columns doesn't fit the secreen, you can still scroll horizontally**.

Any ideas?

Docs aren't helpful:

- Official - nothing about that function
- [Unofficial](http://www.osakac.ac.jp/labs/koeda/tmp/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Worksheet/PHPExcel_Worksheet.html#methodfreezePane)

Comment: Doesn't setting the cell reference to `A7` (column `A`) achieve what you want? If not, then the option isn't available in PHPExcel... perhaps raising an issue (as an enhancement request) on the [PHPExcel Issues page](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues) would help

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you very much! If only it was documented better, this wouldn't be an issue. (For example: this doesn't look much but you are always one ctrl+f away from the answer - http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html).

Comment: I've been very tempted to give up on the documentation, because 95% of the queries here on SO needn't even have been asked if people bothered to read the documentation, so it seems rather pointless spending time on it... thanks for giving me a reason to continue

Comment: @MarkBaker Man, keep up the great work! I haven't tried other excel libraries for php because I started with the right one! Regarding the docs, you know the rule: if it's not on the 1st page of google - it doesn't exist. Any faster lookup would do. Again, thank you for being a part of the community! You are awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane("A7");
```

Credits for this answer goes to @MarkBaker: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910349/phpexcel-freezepane-makes-it-impossible-to-scroll-horizontally-if-columns-does?noredirect=1#comment61383572_36910349)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that only need to call the first column and the second row.

Like this `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane("A2");`

This will freeze the first row and let you scroll horizontally.